# UITextView interprets an Url with a ? wrongly, when a German umlaut is in the link

Tags: ios, url, parameters, uitextview

I created a simple UITextView and added a URL in there. The field is not editable and the Datadetector is set to "Links" The following URL is in the Textfield
[https://www.freizeitparkcheck.de/index.php?thread/6521-ä](https://www.freizeitparkcheck.de/index.php?thread/6521-%C3%A4)

The link appears correctly and the user can click on it.
Unfortunately the ? will be interpreted as %3F instead of the parameter of the url.
After several tests it appears, that the German Umlaut "ä" is the issue. When I remove it, then the url is correctly interpreted and transferred.

when I add the shouldInteractWithURL(), then I can see that the url is changed to:

```
https://www.freizeitparkcheck.de/index.php%3Fthread/6521-%C3%A4
```

When I remove the last "ä", then everything goes fine. Is this a bug in iOS or is there something I have to care about?

UPDATE:
-> looks like ther is an bug in iOS even in version 15.0 because there is no code where I can manage this as it is completly done iOS internally.

Comment: You need the `.urlQueryAllowed` character set to encode the string properly.

Comment: Ok, for all for Information, the Issue is solved from Apple with iOS 15.4 beta 1